# Pandas DataFrame: Count number of cells with numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dummy df:

```
columns = ['answer']
data = ['hello there', '-1', '0.5', '112', 'hello world I am 99 years old', '33 or 1', '19.20', '5+5-10+0.2', 'x=20']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, data=data)
```

I want to count the entries that ONLY include numbers or numbers and +- signs (integers, float, positive, negative) and NO other text. For the dummy df this would be 5. Namely, all entries besides "hello world I am 99 years old", "x=20" and "33 or 1")
My approach is as follows:

```
def find_numbers(some_value):
  if isinstance(some_value, int) or isinstance(some_value, float):
    True
df['answer'].apply(lambda x: len([t for t in x.split() if find_numbers(t)])).sum()
```

Unfortunately, it returns 0. 
Expected output: `5` 
That would be the entries -1, 0.5, 112, 19.20, 5+5-10+0.2.

I guess I need to anyway change it to regex as negative numbers and numbers with '+' are not being counted?

- How would it look like if I wanted to ONLY count the number of entries that include numbers AND text (i.e. "hello world I am 99 years old", "x=20" and "33 or 1")?

Comment: can you post your expected output from the given sample dataframe?

Comment: What about `5+5-10+0.2`; is it counted as "only numbers"?

Comment: @MustafaAydın Good one, I missed it. Yes.

Comment: You want to count `5+5-10+0.2`? Because it evaluates to a number? So expected output is `5` not `4`?

Comment: @HenryEcker correct. Sorry I forgot about that but now edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going for a regex that ensures by `^`  and `$` that the entire string has either `-, +, digit, .`:

```
non_text_count = df.answer.str.contains("^[-+\d\.]+$").sum()
# gives 5
```

> How would it look like [...] to count the number of entries that include numbers **AND** text

With a naive approach, we can chain two regexes:

```
contains_text = df.answer.str.contains("[A-Za-z]+")
contains_nums = df.answer.str.contains("[-+\d\.]+")
text_and_num_count = (contains_text & contains_nums).sum()
# gives 3
```

Comment: Great, thanks. What's the pandas operations for `contains_text but not contains_nums`? `df[df['answer'].str.contains(contains_nums) == False]` doesn't seem to work

Comment: Solved. `contains_no_nums = (df.answer.str.contains("[-+\d\.]+") == False)` works.